# Performance of SUM Columns using CASE COUNT

Tags: mysql

I have a query that summarizes the total of a new buyer and returning buyer.

**t_so_salesorder** table looks like this

```
create_time |  code  | member_name | financial_status
2019-01-01    190001      Qwerty            3
2019-01-01    190002      Ytrewq            3
2019-01-01    190003      Poiuyt            1
2019-01-01    190004      Zxcvbn            3
```

My query looks like this.

```
SELECT
    T1.YC
    , T1.MC
    , SUM(T1.NewBuyer)
    , SUM(T1.RetBuyer)
FROM
(SELECT
    YEAR(A.create_time) AS YC
    , DATE_FORMAT(A.create_time, '%M') AS MC
    , CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(t1.create_time) = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS NewBuyer
    , CASE
        WHEN COUNT(t1.create_time) > 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS RetBuyer
FROM 
    db_bb_mall_trade1_prod.t_so_salesorder a
JOIN 
    db_bb_mall_trade1_prod.t_so_salesorder t1 ON a.member_name = t1.member_name AND a.create_time >= t1.create_time and t1.financial_status = 3
WHERE YEAR(A.create_time) BETWEEN YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND YEAR(CURDATE()) AND a.financial_status = 3
GROUP BY a.create_time, a.member_name, a.code) T1
GROUP BY T1.YC, T1.MC
ORDER BY T1.YC ASC, T1.MC ASC;
```

and the output looks like this

```
YC   |    MC  | NewBuyer | RetBuyer
2019   January    300        400
2019   February   130        500
2019    March     210        110
.
.
.
```

The output is exactly like I wanted but the problem is, my query is taking way too long to generate. It's taking about 2 minutes for only 14 rows. Can you suggesting a more simple and efficient query for me. Thank you.

EDIT: This is the `explain` result

```
id | select_type |  table  | type |         possible_keys      | key | key_len | ref |    rows    | Extra
1      PRIMARY    <derived2>  ALL               null             null   null     null  11720877169  Using temporary; Using filesort
2      DERIVED        t1      ALL  IDX_SALESORDERSUM_CREATETIME  null   null     null     108263    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2      DERIVED        a       ALL  IDX_SALESORDERSUM_CREATETIME  null   null     null     108263    Range checked for each record (index map: 0x10)
```

Comment: Can you add problem statement for more clarity?

Comment: You can type `EXPLAIN` at the beginning of your query, run it then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60203438/edit) to paste the `EXPLAIN` results.

Comment: @tcadidot0 I already add the `explain`, can you please look at it

Comment: 11 billion rows!? Which table is that?

Comment: @tcadidot0 I only use 1 table

Comment: Oh my bad.. Can you do another thing please? Run this query `SHOW CREATE TABLE t_so_salesorder ` and update your question with the result. thanks

Comment: It's not the JOIN or the CASE; it's the lack of INDEX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at that `11720877169`.  It is probably `108263*108263`.  Smells like a "cross join", as if there is no `ON` clause, or it involves un-indexed columns.  Add this to t_so_salesorder

```
ADD INDEX(member_name)
```

That will make the query run orders of magnitude faster.

But, you can still do better.  Let's change

```
            FROM  db_bb_mall_trade1_prod.t_so_salesorder a
            JOIN  db_bb_mall_trade1_prod.t_so_salesorder t1
                          ON a.member_name = t1.member_name
              AND  a.create_time >= t1.create_time
              and  t1.financial_status = 3
            WHERE  YEAR(A.create_time) BETWEEN YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
                                           AND YEAR(CURDATE())
              AND  a.financial_status = 3
```

to

```
            FROM  db_bb_mall_trade1_prod.t_so_salesorder a
            JOIN  db_bb_mall_trade1_prod.t_so_salesorder t1
                   ON a.member_name = t1.member_name
                  AND a.financial_status = t1.financial_status
                  AND  a.create_time >= t1.create_time
            WHERE  A.create_time >= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-01-01')
              AND  A.create_time <= CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-12-31')
              AND  a.financial_status = 3

ADD INDEX(financial_status, member_name, create_time)
```

That will

- Make the test on `create_time` "sargable".
- Get rid of the bug with New Year's Day.  (`BETWEEN` is inclusive.)
- Run faster than with the single-column INDEX previously mentioned.

Since you seem to be doing a "groupwise-max", there are even faster ways.  But I will let you digest these improvements first.

Also, I doubt if you need a subquery.  (Again, I would rather see you rewrite before tackling any further rewrites.)